# ImageGenerator using Resnet

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am trying to build a image generator that will:

1. Take in a raw image
2. Read in the image and resize it to (224,224,3) for resnet50
3. Perform data augmentation on it (rotation, flipping, etc.)
4. Create a Resnet50 feature for it (using model.predict)
5. Then output this in the image generator via yield method

What I cannot figure out is how to actually do this. I am making this as a triple loss so one image is an anchor, positive, and negative image.

It says:

> TypeError: len() of unsized object

### Updates

I have changed the code a bit but now it is giving me this error.

```
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that a network expects a batch size. if you're submitting only one image of shape (244,244,3), you'll need to first `np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)` to achieve shape (1,244,244,3) prior to prediction. That will be 1 image of 244 by 244 with 3 layers, i.e. (1,244,244,3).

It seems like you have some other dimensions, but the point remains, get that batch size dimension in there; that's what your recent error is saying.

Comment: I fixed the above error but now its giving me something odd. Please see my update